# How to use OR-Tools Routing Library to solve a CVRP with loading and unloading different order types?

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

Let's say we have three nodes (Node1, Node2, and Node3) to service. Node1 needs to return 2 blue boxes to the depot. Both Node2 and Node3 need to receive 1 yellow box from the depot. There are two identical vehicles available. Each vehicle can carry a maximum of 3 boxes (blue and/or yellow). So we have:

Demands[blue] = [2, 0, 0]
Demands[yellow] = [0, -1, -1]

I cannot just create a dimension to deal with demands globally because I would have
Demands[global] = [2, -1, -1] and the route

{Depot load(0) -> Node1 load(2) -> Node2 load(1) -> Node3 load(0) -> Depot load(0) }

would be feasible. However, as the two blue boxes from Node1 cannot be used to service Node2 and Node3, the real load record for this route should be

{Depot load(2) -> Node1 load(4) -> Node2 load(3) -> Node3 load(2) -> Depot load(2) }

and since this route would violate the vehicle capacity, it actually is infeasible. I would like to also create a dimension for each individual demand and somehow make

dimensionGlobal = dimensionBlue + dimensionYellow.

I don’t know if this is possible. If it’s possible, how can I do it? If it’s not, what else can I do?

I'm working with the c++ library version. Thanks.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h"
#include "ortools/constraint_solver/routing_enums.pb.h"
#include "ortools/constraint_solver/routing_index_manager.h"
#include "ortools/constraint_solver/routing_parameters.h"

namespace operations_research {
    struct DataModel {
        const std::vector<std::vector<int64_t>> distance_matrix{
            {0, 696, 548, 776},
            {696, 0, 308, 992},
            {548, 308, 0, 684},
            {776, 992, 684, 0},
        };
        const std::vector<std::vector<int64_t>> demands{
            //0   1   2  3
            { 0,  2,  0,  0}, //  blue box
            { 0,  0, -1, -1}, //  yellow box
            { 0,  2, -1, -1}, //  "global" box
        };
        const std::vector<int64_t> vehicle_capacities{ 3, 3 };
        const int num_vehicles = 2;
        const RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex depot{ 0 };
    };

    //! @brief Print the solution.
    //! @param[in] data Data of the problem.
    //! @param[in] manager Index manager used.
    //! @param[in] routing Routing solver used.
    //! @param[in] solution Solution found by the solver.
    void PrintResults(const DataModel& data, const RoutingIndexManager& manager,
        const RoutingModel& routing, const Assignment& solution) {
        int64_t total_distance{ 0 };
        int64_t total_load{ 0 };
        const size_t INDEX{2}; // SET THE LOAD TYPE {0, 1, or 2} TO BE PRINTED HERE!!!
        RoutingDimension* dimension = routing.GetMutableDimension("Capacity" + std::to_string(INDEX));
        for (int vehicle_id = 0; vehicle_id < data.num_vehicles; ++vehicle_id) {
            int64_t index = routing.Start(vehicle_id);
            LOG(INFO) << "Route for Vehicle " << vehicle_id << ":";
            int64_t route_distance{ 0 };
            int64_t route_load{ 0 };
            std::stringstream route;
        while (routing.IsEnd(index) == false)
        {
            int64_t node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index).value();
            route_load += data.demands[2][node_index];
            int64_t previous_index = index;
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index));
            route << " -> " << node_index
                << " B(" << solution.Value(blue->CumulVar(index)) << ")"
                << "Y(" << solution.Value(yellow->CumulVar(index)) << ")"
                << "G(" << solution.Value(generic->CumulVar(index)) << ")";
            route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(previous_index, index,
                int64_t{ vehicle_id });
        };
                route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(previous_index, index,
                    int64_t{ vehicle_id });
            };

            LOG(INFO) << route.str() << " -> " << manager.IndexToNode(index).value();
            LOG(INFO) << "Distance of the route: " << route_distance << "m";
            LOG(INFO) << "Load of the route: " << route_load;
            total_distance += route_distance;
            total_load += route_load;
        }
        LOG(INFO) << "Total distance of all routes: " << total_distance << "m";
        LOG(INFO) << "Total load of all routes: " << total_load;
        LOG(INFO) << "";
        LOG(INFO) << "Advanced usage:";
        LOG(INFO) << "Problem solved in " << routing.solver()->wall_time() << "ms";
    }

    void PrintSolution(const DataModel& data, const RoutingIndexManager& manager,
        const RoutingModel& routing, const Assignment& solution)
    {
        std::tuple<double, double> result = std::make_tuple(0.0, 0.0);

        switch (routing.status())
        {
        case RoutingModel::ROUTING_SUCCESS:
            LOG(INFO) << "Problem solved successfully after calling RoutingModel::Solve().";
            PrintResults(data, manager, routing, solution);
            break;
        case RoutingModel::ROUTING_PARTIAL_SUCCESS_LOCAL_OPTIMUM_NOT_REACHED:
            LOG(INFO) << "Problem solved successfully after calling RoutingModel::Solve(), except "
                << "that a local optimum has not been reached. Leaving more time would allow "
                << "improving the solution.";
            PrintResults(data, manager, routing, solution);
            break;
        case RoutingModel::ROUTING_INFEASIBLE:
            LOG(INFO) << "The problem was proven infeasible.";
            break;
        case RoutingModel::ROUTING_INVALID:
            LOG(INFO) << "Model, model parameters or flags are not valid. ";
            break;
        case RoutingModel::ROUTING_FAIL:
            LOG(INFO) << "No solution found to the problem after calling RoutingModel::Solve().";
            break;
        case RoutingModel::ROUTING_FAIL_TIMEOUT:
            LOG(INFO) << "Time limit reached before finding a solution with RoutingModel::Solve().";
            break;
        case RoutingModel::ROUTING_NOT_SOLVED:
            LOG(INFO) << "Problem not solved yet (before calling RoutingModel::Solve()).";
            break;
        default:
            LOG(INFO) << "Undefined Status: " << routing.status();
            break;
        }
    }

    void VrpCapacity() {
        // Instantiate the data problem.
        DataModel data;

        // Create Routing Index Manager
        RoutingIndexManager manager(data.distance_matrix.size(), data.num_vehicles,
            data.depot);

        // Create Routing Model.
        RoutingModel routing(manager);

        // Create and register a transit callback.
        const int transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(
            [&data, &manager](int64_t from_index, int64_t to_index) -> int64_t {
                // Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
                int from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index).value();
        int to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index).value();
        return data.distance_matrix[from_node][to_node];
            });

        // Define cost of each arc.
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index);

        // Add Capacity constraint.
        for (size_t i = 0; i < data.demands.size(); i++)
        {
            const int demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
                [&data, &manager, i](int64_t from_index) -> int64_t {
                    // Convert from routing variable Index to demand NodeIndex.
                    int from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index).value();
            return data.demands[i][from_node];
                });
            routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
                demand_callback_index,    // transit callback index
                int64_t{ 0 },               // capacity slack
                data.vehicle_capacities,  // vehicle maximum capacities
                false,                     // start cumul to zero
                "Capacity" + std::to_string(i));
        }

        // Setting first solution heuristic.
        RoutingSearchParameters search_parameters = DefaultRoutingSearchParameters();
        search_parameters.set_first_solution_strategy(
            FirstSolutionStrategy::PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC);
        search_parameters.set_local_search_metaheuristic(
            LocalSearchMetaheuristic::GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH);
        search_parameters.mutable_time_limit()->set_seconds(1);

        // Solve the problem.
        const Assignment* solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters);

        // Print solution on console.
        PrintSolution(data, manager, routing, *solution);
    }
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[]) {
    operations_research::VrpCapacity();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[OR-Tools git hub related discussion](https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/3749)